# Host two sites with Vagrant on two different domains

Tags: networking, dns

I would like to host two different web sites on my computer. One is a Laravel application served with Nginx, and the second is a .NET Core ASP app. I would like to host them in two different Vagrant boxes on the same machine. How would I accomplish, that each site has its own domain? Can I just set the A records of both domains to the same IP? How do I forward ports if both applications should run on eg. port 80? Do I need any additional tools and how sould I configure them? Could it be done with a DDNS, so I wouldn't have to get a static IP for my machine?